# MySQL DECIMAL storage and max number of digits

Tags: mysql, storage

It's really a quick question but I really can't find the answer to it.
When you store a number like 57 in a decimal column with max 65 digits, does it take the space for 65 digits to store it or not?

I'm concerned with it because I checked the space used by my table with 4 DECIMAL columns, it said 65536 bytes. Then I decided to set max digit number to 40 for all DECIMAL columns. Then the space used got to 49152 bytes. On second thought I decided to set a max 15 digit length for two of the four columns and the number of bytes used remained the same (49152).

This is what I use to look up the space taken by every table
SELECT table_name, ((data_length + index_length)) as "size in B" FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = "db_name"

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Every number will take the same space. According to the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html it's 4 bytes per 9 digits + 0-4 bytes for the remaining digits. So for 65 digits it should be 7*4 + 1 = 29 bytes.

Comment: "So for 65 digits it should be 7*4 + 1 = 29 bytes.", this is not completely true. It depends on the configuration of integer parts and fractional parts, you can read more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html